# How to use Carousel from bootstrap(5.1v) only in react?

Tags: reactjs, sass, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-carousel

With only installing `bootstrap` in `create-react-app` unable to navigate to the next and previous slide. Here I'm using `bootstrap` class with `HTML`.

*P.S : Only with `bootstrap` not `react-bootrap`.*

*Carousel.js*

```
export default function Carousel() {
  return (
    <div className="Carousel">
      <div
        id="carouselExampleIndicators"
        class="carousel slide"
        data-bs-ride="carousel"
      >
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide-to="0"
            class="active"
            aria-current="true"
            aria-label="Slide 1"
          ></button>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide-to="1"
            aria-label="Slide 2"
          ></button>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide-to="2"
            aria-label="Slide 3"
          ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img
              src="https://www.whats-on-netflix.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/naruto-on-netflix.jpg"
              class="d-block w-100"
              alt="naruto"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img
              src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EZVmgtkVcAAYpWP.jpg"
              class="d-block w-100"
              alt="eren"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img
              src="https://media.comicbook.com/2021/06/dragon-ball-z-goku-1273631-1280x0.jpeg"
              class="d-block w-100"
              alt="goku"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-prev"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide="prev"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-next"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide="next"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here I'm using scss and imported bootstrap scss in `style.scss` and imported in `App.js`

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Is any dependency missing to be added?

[CODESANDBOX LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-nightingale-iunnw?file=/src/Carousel.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only use `bootstrap` you need to handle the `Carousel` state on your own.

You can try using `useState` to handle the selected image like below. You can conditionally set the `button` and `image` element `class` names to get the correct `CSS` applied.

I also used `classnames` package to set the class names nicely.

**Solution 1**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

const images = [
  {
    url:
      "https://www.whats-on-netflix.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/naruto-on-netflix.jpg",
    alt: "naruto"
  },
  {
    url: "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EZVmgtkVcAAYpWP.jpg",
    alt: "eren"
  },
  {
    url:
      "https://media.comicbook.com/2021/06/dragon-ball-z-goku-1273631-1280x0.jpeg",
    alt: "goku"
  }
];
export default function Carousel() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleNext = () => {
    setIndex((prevIndex) =>
      prevIndex < images.length - 1 ? prevIndex + 1 : 0
    );
  };

  const handlePrev = () => {
    setIndex((prevIndex) =>
      prevIndex > 0 ? prevIndex - 1 : images.length - 1
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="Carousel">
      <div
        id="carouselExampleIndicators"
        class="carousel slide"
        data-bs-ride="carousel"
      >
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          {Array.from(Array(images.length).keys()).map((buttonIndex) => (
            <button
              type="button"
              data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
              data-bs-slide-to={buttonIndex}
              class={classNames({
                active: buttonIndex === index
              })}
              aria-current="true"
              aria-label={`Slide ${buttonIndex + 1}`}
              onClick={() => setIndex(buttonIndex)}
            ></button>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          {images.map(({ url, alt }, imageIndex) => (
            <div
              class={classNames("carousel-item", {
                active: imageIndex === index
              })}
            >
              <img src={url} class="d-block w-100" alt={alt} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-prev"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide="prev"
          onClick={handlePrev}
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-next"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide="next"
          onClick={handleNext}
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-kirch-235v5?file=/src/Carousel.js

**Solution 2**

You can include JS and CSS bundle given in the [docs](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-glitter-ttqqe?file=/public/index.html).

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-glitter-ttqqe?file=/public/index.html

Comment: @Hithesh k, check this out !!

Comment: thanks that works !!, can we retain carousel transition https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/